# Automatización con C# usando SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Tags: c#

Hola: Para acceder a los controles que están en frame en algún portal que se desea automatizar generalmente ocupo:

```
SHDocVw.InternetExplorer MiIE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
var ElFrame = MiIE.Document.getElementById("sidebar");
var ElLinnk = ElFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementById("Link3");
ElLinnk.Click();
```

Sin embargo, con un portal lo anterior no está funcionando. 
¿Conocen otra forma para poder conseguirlo? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Que es lo que notas por lo cual no funciona? obtienes algun mensaje de error, o simplemente no realiza la funcionalidad que esperas al acceder los componentes

Comment: Si es para automatizar no evaluaste utilizar Selenium? para automatizar codigo de unit test es la libreria ideal, aunque habria que ver como se lleva con los frame https://www.guru99.com/selenium-csharp-tutorial.html

Comment: Con el portal que intento automatizar para usar selenium necesito una configuración especifica de administrador que no voy a conseguir, por eso recurro al SHDocVw.InternetExplorer().

Comment: Pero selenium no se usa con un portal, aplica en los unit test que defines en tu codigo c#, no deberias cambiar nada en el cliente para usar esta libreria de automatizacion